# Taking numeric (integer) input from user and inserting it in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I also want to compare the max number but I am having problems with inserting it in an array - it gives the error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Whenever I insert a value larger than 5.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LargestValue 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
        int a[] = new int[5];

        System.out.println ("Enter 5 numbers for comparison ");

        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
        {
            int inputNumber = sc.nextInt();
            a[inputNumber] = inputNumber;
            System.out.println(inputNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You meant to use `a[j] = inputNumber;` instead of `a[inputNumber] = inputNumber;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign the inputs to the j'th position of the array, not to the `inputNumber` position :

```
a[j] = inputNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

First error is already postet `a[j] = inputNumber;`

To compare the array you can use `Arrays.sort(a);`

> Arrays.sort(int): Sorts the specified array into ascending numerical order.

To get the max value you can use `Arrays.stream(a).max().getAsInt();`